# Lowest version of JQuery usable with Foundation 6

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I have a site that is based on an old framework which uses deprecated jquery functions so later versions cause conflicts. Jquery 1.4.2 is the highest version usable.

Currently, I have a template based on bootstrap but looking at rebuilding using Foundation so wondered if anyone had any idea what the lowest version of jquery usable with foundation 6 is.

Rebuilding the framework isn't an option right now.

Comment: not at all likely it will work with 1.4 which is extremely old ( released 7 years ago) and doesn't include delegation methods like `on()` which are heavily used by UI libraries these days

Comment: Could you use jQuery `noConflict()` and add a newer version of jQuery? Foundation 5 has / had a requirement for v2.0.3 of jQuery so 6 will be + that and even with jQuery Migrate, it's unlikely to work